# Difference between FIPS 196 and SSL for authentication?

Tags: tls, authentication, fips

I want to know the difference between FIPS 196 (public key for authentication) and SSL for authentication. If we claim FIPS 196, which is the core of most authentication protocols in use (e.g. SSL) is it ok?

And if we use SSL for authentication between client and server can we claim implementation FIPS 196?

Comment: FIPS 196 has been obsoleted. Why would you want to use it?

Comment: for CA (CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY) better use this standard. I want to know that ssl and fips is same, or if we use ssl can told compatible with fips 196?

Answer (score 1):

FIPS 196 introduces two-step authentication based on Digital Signatures.

Authentication using SSL uses FIPS 140-2.